# Mapping swagger page to APIM

Tags: swagger-ui, azure-api-management

I have an existing site which I want to use APIM with and I have successfully mapped my APIs across to APIM. However, I have a swagger page which I just want to be available in the same domain as APIM. How can I do this? The swagger page is:

https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/index.html

I want this to come across as something like

https://myapidomain.com/swagger

My apis in APIM are of the form so I want the swagger to match the same domain

https://myapidomain.com/api/myfirstapi

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a few caveats depending on how complex your web page is:

1. Create an API with URL suffix of "swagger"
2. Optionally uncheck "Require subscription" from that API to make it anonymous
3. Create inner operation with URL template of "/" and GET method
4. Add policies to operation inbound:

   `<set-backend-service base-url="https://mysite.azurewebsites.net" />
   <rewrite-uri template="/api/swagger/index.html" />`
5. Test and adjust

That will take care of the page itself. There will be problems if page uses cookies or references external scripts/images via relative URIs. Cookies will be a problem because they'll come with domain set to "mysite.azurewebsites.net", so you need to take care of this in policies.

Resources with relative URLs are problem because browser will make additional requests to your APIM service with those URLs, so you'll need to create additional operations to cover those requests. Using * in operation template might help cover multiple resources.